# Get latitude and longitude from map object using selector gadget in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, geolocation

I'm doing data scraping(for the first time) in R by using selectorGadget extension for chrome ,which uses the **package "rvest"**
[this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/) is the reference from which I'm doing

and from [this](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/Multistorey-Apartment-real-estate-Mumbai) website I'm trying to fetch data

this is my code

```
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- 'http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/Multistorey-Apartment-real-estate-Mumbai'

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

map_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.iconMap .stop-propagation')
map <- html_text(map_data_html)
head(map)
```

but this gives me only the text as "map" , I want to access the lat and long attribute inside this map. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not optimal but this is one way to get the lat/lon values:

```
map_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.iconMap .stop-propagation')
map = html_attr(map_data_html,"data-link") # get the data-link part

lat = as.numeric(str_match(map, "lat=(.*?)&longt")[,2]) # find the lat
lon = as.numeric(str_match(map, "longt=(.*?)&projectOr")[,2]) # find the lon
```

Comment: yeahh... achieved...is working fine for me .. Thanks a ton @timfaber

Comment: No problem :) Guess there is not really an easier way given that the lat/lon values are hidden in the link